# React redux form FieldArray.map() does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to create FieldArray. I got sth like this:

```
<form>
  <FieldArray
    name="styles"
    component={this.renderStyles}
  />
</form>
```

and then:

```
renderStyles = (props) => {
  return(
    <ul>
    {props.fields.map((style, index) =>{
    console.log(style)
    return(
      <li key={style} className="field-item">
        <label>{style}</label>
        <Field
            name={`${style}`}
            component="input"
            type="checkbox"
        />
      </li>)
  }
)} 
</ul>
)}
```

I also do initialize the values for FieldArray like this:

```
initialValues:{styles:[{style:'somestyle', img:'someimgurl'}]}
```

However the `console.log(style)` in renderStyles showes me only `styles[0]` as a string. No way to obtain the object. I tried different ways. HELP DERP! Please :)

Comment: ok, never mind. After hours of tortures `props.fields.getAll().map...` does the trick finally... Isn't it a bug in FieldArray though?

Comment: Put that as an answer then and mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

ok, never mind. After hours of tortures props.fields.getAll().map... does the trick finally... Isn't it a bug in FieldArray though?